# Request Failed on production apk

Tags: android, android-pay

I'm always getting this error when try to request for maskedWallet in production apk.

[image]

Things that I've already check:

- I've already check the public key and it was correct.
- Merchant is enabled in google play console and it was fine.
- It was working well on test environment.
- Wallet api was also enabled in my Manifest.
- Also production apk env was set to `WalletConstants.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION`

Anything else I'm missing that might caused this error?

Comment: did you solved that error.?

Comment: did you solve that? is it caused by signing?

Comment: @PakHoCheung unfortunately I still haven't figured this out and problem still occurring in production. We decide to remove android pay option bcoz of this problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure You have added the metadata Tag..

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled" android:value="true" />
```

In the android Manifest....

If this doesn't helps you...please consider posting the Logcat Logs...

Comment: Forgot to include in my question but yeah I already have this in my Manifest but still getting those errors. I also tried running the app with release configs to check logs but there's nothing in the logs. No error were returned by android pay. Thanks by the way, man.

Answer (score 1):

You get this message with no error code because you haven't get approval from Google.

1. Sign up the form - https://services.google.com/fb/forms/googlepayAPIenable/
2. Then, Google will contact you

   A. They need your apk pointed to ENVIRONMENT_TEST.

   B: If your app is ok after their review, you need to submit more information related to your app.

   C: They need you apk pointed to ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION and you need to sign your app.

So, just follow their instructions.

**Some References:**

Deploying your application from testing

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/test-and-deploy

Signing

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html