# Android app signing for Google pay with Stripe as processor

Tags: android, google-play, stripe-payments, android-app-signing, google-pay

First, I am getting a same error as this post [Request Failed on production apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587984/request-failed-on-production-apk)

Then, I did some searches. I guess I need to sign my app with release keys. [Tutorial for Test and Deploy](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/test-and-deploy)

I follow [Tutorial for Signing App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) to sign my app. I did

1. Generate a key and keystore (in Android Studio)
2. Manually sign an APK (in Android Studio)
3. Enable Google Play App Signing (in Google Console)

[image]

4. Follow -Tutorial for Test and Deploy- to check CERT.RSA using `jar -xvf  META-INF/CERT.RSA`

but receive

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: META-INF/CERT.RSA (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:305)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1233)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong command line jar instruction (I've not sure where you got this from). Your command is looking for a file called CERT.RSA. Instead you need to look at your APK. Try:

`jar -tvf foo.apk META-INF`

where `foo.apk` is the name of your APK file to list everything in your APK META-INF directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error means I need to submit a form to Google in order to use Google Pay. Here is details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49501813/5737856